# new disk in Vm shows as ata2

Tags: mount, hard-disk, vmware

The admin added a new disk to my VM and it appears as `ata2` after I rescanned the scsi controller with:

```
root@jpax-build07:~# echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
root@jpax-build07:~# echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/scan
root@jpax-build07:~# echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/scan
fdisk -l
```

but it doesn't show under `fdisk -l` how can I create a fs and mount it?

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 300 GiB, 322122547200 bytes, 629145600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa8c4da68
...
```

`/dev/sda` is the existing disk

dmesg:

```
[10600270.932925] ata2: soft resetting link
[10600271.122685] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/33
[10600271.123105] ata2: EH complete
[10600430.666938] ata1: soft resetting link
[10600430.836638] ata1: EH complete
[10600467.936948] ata2: soft resetting link
[10600468.122680] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/33
[10600468.123125] ata2: EH complete
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ata is for IDE disks. ( Actually a stronger telltale is UDMA/33 )

As such the hotplug SCSI commands that you are using for scanning the SCSI bus for new disks, won't make the kernel show any new disks at all (the new  disk is in an emulated IDE bus after all).

If you want to do new disks hotplug in your VMs, you have to ask your VMWare admin to create new virtual disks as (emulated) SCSI disks instead.

TLDR the Linux kernel does not support hot add of IDE disks. After rebooting that VM, a new disk will appear.